# Get distinct objects for foreign key in existing Django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

Consider the following many-to-one relationship. Users can own many widgets:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')

class User(models.Model):
    pass
```

I have a fairly complicated query that returns me a queryset of Widgets. From that I want to list the distinct values of User.

I know I could loop my Widgets and pull out users with `.values('owner')` or `{% regroup ... %}` but the dataset is huge and I'd like to do this at the database so it actually returns Users not Widgets first time around.

My best idea to date is pulling out a `.values_list('owner', flat=True)` and then doing a `User.objects.filter(pk__in=...)` using that. That pulls it back to two queries but that still seems like more than it should need to be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding your Widgets query to a query like User.objects.get(widgets__in=...) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backward relationship:

```
User.objects.distinct().filter(widget__in=your_widget_queryset)
```

Comment: That does indeed work. Needs `.distinct()` on the end to stop duplication but yeah, that works quite well. I always thought the `__in` modifier only worked on arrays but it's nice to see it being fairly intelligent.

Comment: This queryset already has `distinct()` call before `filter()`

Comment: So it does. You have my apologies.

Comment: After looking into so many resources and QnA here, this is what works very well. Most of the answers offer distinct('xyz') as a solution which is for postgres and not for mysql.